How to change background color of loading page of a WASM app?
I am working on a WASM standalone application and simply trying to change the color of the loading page. By default it is white.
Here is what I have tried (in Index.html):
<body>
    <div style="background-color: red" id="app">
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

-> The page remains white until Home page is loaded.
2nd thing I tried (same code as above, only adding style attribute to body here):
<body style="background-color: red" >

-> The page is white, then red, then Home page is loaded, still not what I want to achieve.
What am I missing here ?

The .NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App project template uses the following HTML markup in index.html:
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

The svg.loading-progress element is removed from the DOM by the Blazor framework when the page loads. If you still have the same HTML markup, then this CSS code will change the body background only while the svg element exists:
body:has(#app > .loading-progress) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Custom or More Flexible Scenarios
A similar mechanism will work even if you don't rely on the default svg element. In this case you can use the HTML markup in the MainLayout.razor. For example, with this index.html...
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

...and this MainLayout.razor...
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    ... anything here...
</div>

You can use this CSS code
body {
    background: yellow; /* during loading */
}

body:has(#app > .page) {
    background: white; /* after loading completes */
}

Without :has()
Finally, if you must support older browsers that don't recognize :has(), you can place two CSS rules in two different places:
/* in the <head> of index.html or in a CSS file in the <head> */
body {
    background: yellow;
}

/* in MainLayout.razor itself, so it ends up in the <body> and after the previous CSS rule */
body {
    background: white;
}

